# Convert SQL server to Teradata Query

Tags: sql-server, teradata

I want to convert the following SQL server query into a Teradata BTEQ script. Could anyone help in this process..

The table creation logic is as follows and this needs to be converted to Teradata

```
CREATE TABLE [Eqp].[t_WSTCPEStairstep]
(
[SysID] [smallint] NULL,
[PrinID] [smallint] NULL,
[Account] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Order_No] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[Order_Typ] [varchar] (1) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Eqp_Serial] [varchar] (25) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Eqp_Typ] [varchar] (2) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Eqp_Model] [varchar] (9) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS NULL,
[Disco_Dte] [date] NULL,
[Return_Dte] [date] NULL,
[Restart_Dte] [date] NULL,
[Lost_Dte] [date] NULL,
[TestFlag] [smallint] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
WITH
(
DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE
)
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ix_WSTCPEStairstepDiscoDteIndex] ON [Eqp].[t_WSTCPEStairstep] ([Disco_Dte]) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX [ix_WSTCPEStairstepSPAIndex] ON [Eqp].[t_WSTCPEStairstep] ([SysID], [Account]) WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your chances of getting an answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about some of the `SQL Server` specific bits (compression, clustered, primary), but this will give you a start:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Eqp.t_WSTCPEStairstep (
  SysID SMALLINT,
  PrinID SMALLINT,
  Account BIGINT NOT NULL,
  Order_No BIGINT NOT NULL,
  Order_Typ VARCHAR(1),
  Eqp_Serial VARCHAR(25),
  Eqp_Typ VARCHAR(2),
  Eqp_Model VARCHAR(9) ,
  Disco_Dte DATE,
  Return_Dte DATE,
  Restart_Dte DATE,
  Lost_Dte DATE,
  TestFlag SNALLINT
) 
PRIMARY INDEX(col1, col2, ...);

-- Indexes
CREATE INDEX ix_WSTCPEStairstepDiscoDteIndex (Disco_Dte) ON Eqp.t_WSTCPEStairstep;
CREATE INDEX ix_WSTCPEStairstepSPAIndex (SysID, Account) ON Eqp.t_WSTCPEStairstep;
```

Which column(s) do you use to access data in this table?  If they provide even distribution (i.e. mostly distinct values), then specify these as your `PRIMARY INDEX` fields.  And if these fields are unique, better yet - `UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX`.  Maybe it's one of the indexes you specified -- `disco_dte` or `(SysID, Account)`.

Some more notes:

- columns should be NULLABLE by default
- if `TestFlag` is just 1/0, you can use the `BYTEINT` data type
- you may want to convert the `VARCHAR(1)` and `VARCHAR(2)` to `CHAR`
- for compression, you can add that at multiple levels, but most common I think is at the column level

Comment: *DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE* is similar to 

   `CREATE TABLE Eqp.t_WSTCPEStairstep, BLOCKCOMPRESSION = ALWAYS (...`

but this is usually set on a system level. Depending on the hardware this might be bad. And the *CLUSTERED INDEX* is similar to `PRIMARY INDEX (SysID, Account)`. The 2nd index might be implemented as partitioning for the table, but this depends on usage and data demographics.